# Erro no "break" em códgo C++ impede a compilação

Tags: c++, case

Segue código:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float n1, n2;
    int s;
    float resul;
    cout << "Digite um número para começar" << endl;
    cin >> n1;

    cout << "Vc quer (1)somar (2)diminuir (3)mutiplicar (4)dividir" << endl;
    cin >> s;
    switch (s) {
    case 1:
        cout << "Com qual valor?" << endl;
        cin >> n2;
        resul = n1 + n2;
        break case 2 : cout << "Com qual valor?" << endl;
        cin >> n2;
        resul = n1 - n2;
        break case 3 : cout << "Com qual valor?" << endl;
        cin >> n2;
        resul = n1 * n2;
        break case 4 : cout << "Com qual valor?" << endl;
        cin >> n2;
        resul = n1 / n2;
        break default : cout << "Error 404" << endl;
    }

    cout << "O resultado é " << resul << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Onde eu errei? É uma calculadora simples.

Comment: Qual é a duvida?

Comment: tava dando erro, mas eu descobri que era pq eu tinha esquecido de colocar o ; depois do Break hehe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não sei já que não tem o que acontece de errado, mas pelo código há erros de digitação, falta o `;` após cada `break`.

Organizando o código um pouco melhor ficaria assim:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    float n1, n2, resultado;
    int s;
    cout << "Digite um número para começar";
    cin >> n1;
    cout << endl << "Vc quer (1)somar (2)diminuir (3)mutiplicar (4)dividir";
    cin >> s;
    cout << endl << "Com qual valor?";
    cin >> n2;
    switch(s) {
    case 1:
        resultado = n1 + n2;
        break;
    case 2:
        resultado = n1 - n2;
        break;
    case 3:
        resultado = n1 * n2;
        break;
    case 4:
        resultado = n1 / n2;
        break;
    default:
        cout << endl << "Error 404";
        return 0;
    }
    cout << endl << "O resultado é " << resultado << endl;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/2cnccW). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/tdkmaatx-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Algorithm/Calculator.cpp).

Comment: kkk Isso msm, sou muito esquecido.Vlw^^

Answer (score 2):

Apenas coloque um `;` após o break.

Comment: na frente ou depois?

Comment: o que sua resposta acrescenta no que já foi dito na outra resposta?